# Recursively searching for file in task freezes form on Mono

Tags: vb.net, search, recursion, mono, task

I am working on a file browser in VB.Net that will be run on Ubuntu on the Mono framework. Everything was going fine up until I decided to implement the search function. I have it set up so that the search runs in a new task, and the user can cancel it from the form. This works fine on Windows, but when run on Mono, I get weird results:

- Sometimes the form freezes (can still be dragged around, but everything inside is unresponsive)
- Sometimes a few search results come up, and then the form freezes
- Since the form is frozen, I cannot click the cancel button and have to force quit
- There are no error messages or exceptions, so I have no idea what is going wrong.
- Sometimes the form artifacts if dragged across screen, even though in theory the search code is running in a separate task

I have tried inserting 'Application.DoEvents()' throughout, but that didn't help. I even tried running the code on the UI thread without a task, but that obviously just causes everything to freeze.

Here is the code:

The Search() method is called through a textbox, when it is called a button to cancel is displayed, and if clicked calls tokenSource2.Cancel()

```
Dim tokenSource2 As New CancellationTokenSource()
Dim ct As CancellationToken = tokenSource2.Token

Private Sub Search(ByVal txt As String, ByVal dir As String)
    CancelSearch()
    tokenSource2 = New CancellationTokenSource()
    ct = tokenSource2.Token
    pnl_cancelsearch.Show()
    Dim t As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                              If ct.IsCancellationRequested Then
                                                  Exit Sub
                                              End If
                                              ListView1.Clear()
                                              Dim iscasesensitive As Boolean = ConfigManager.SearchIsCaseSensitive
                                              If Not searchhistory.Contains(txt) Then
                                                  searchhistory.Add(txt)
                                                  combo_search.Items.Add(txt)
                                              End If
                                              If ct.IsCancellationRequested Then
                                                  Exit Sub
                                              End If
                                              If dir = "" Then
                                                  For Each item As String In Directory.GetLogicalDrives
                                                      If ct.IsCancellationRequested Then
                                                          Exit Sub
                                                      End If
                                                      SearchRec(txt, item, iscasesensitive)
                                                  Next
                                              Else
                                                  SearchRec(txt, dir)
                                              End If
                                              pnl_cancelsearch.Hide()
                                          End Sub)
End Sub

Private Sub SearchRec(ByVal txt As String, ByVal rootdir As String, Optional ByVal casesensitive As Boolean = True)
    For Each item As String In Directory.GetFiles(rootdir)
        If ct.IsCancellationRequested Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If casesensitive Then
            If item.Contains(txt) Then
                AddItem(item)
            End If
        Else
            If item.ToLower.Contains(txt.ToLower) Then
                AddItem(item)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each item As String In Directory.GetDirectories(rootdir)
        If ct.IsCancellationRequested Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        SearchRec(txt, item)
    Next
End Sub
```

How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong? It works perfectly fine on Windows, but not on Mono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, thanks to another user, was to use **BeginInvoke** when updating the UI, which worked perfectly.

Comment: Just remember to call `EndInvoke` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have here a problem: you're modifying the UI and you want your task to be executed as a new thread (because you're not using await so there's no shared time if it's being excuted on the main thread).

If you force the task to create a new thread (and for that you must explicitly set TaskScheduler.Default as the used task scheduler) then the UI code will lead to a cross threading exception. And if you don't force the task to be run on a new thread then it is executed on the main thread blocking it.

Mono Forms implementation is poor at a minimum, so its a lot slower than on Windows, it can perfectly being that on Windows you don't notice the slowness because it's fast enough and on another OS using Mono it's slower and you notice the UI update.

First of all, if you can, avoid using Forms on Mono, use GTK# or another UI kit.

Also, sepparate the UI logic from the data logic, create a task which retrieves all the data (using a task or the thread pool) and when you got it then update the UI, my bet is you will still find it slow because the UI update.

Comment: The UI completely freezes and never comes back to being responsive, I have to force quit it. I understand the issue with the cross threading, but I want the search to populate the list view as it finds items, otherwise the user could wait for a while with a blank list view.

Comment: The BeginInvoke was what I was looking for